# Applying css to Django generated form objects for textarea

Tags: css, django, forms, templates

The following screenshot shows the forms.py code for generating the `textarea` input box on the right-hand side (which has placeholder text: "Your comment to the world").

[image]

The CSS however, is applied only to the pure HTML `textarea` box (to the left) and I cannot figure out how to get it to be applied to the Django generated `textarea` input box. You'll notice that the CSS has been automatically applied to the top 'Name' text input field.

**The styles.css code is here:**

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}
h1 {
  color: red;
  text-shadow: 3px 2px grey;
  font-family: Arial
}
p {
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial
}


input[type=text] {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 21px 20px;
  margin: 14px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 33;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Arial
}

textarea[type=textarea] {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 21px 20px;
  margin: 14px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 33;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-family: Arial
}
```

**forms.py (as shown above with the rendering of HTML) is below**

```
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=20,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Your Name Please'}))
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Your comment to the world'}))
```

And finally, **the sign.html page** (with the HTML for the relevant page) is below

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'guestbook/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Tell the world how you're doing!</h1>
<h2>Sign the guestbook</h2>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Enter your name:<br>
  <!--<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name here">-->
   {{form.name}}
  <br>
 Enter your comment:<br>
  <textarea name="message" type="Textarea" placeholder="Your comment here" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
  {{form.comment}}
  <br><br>

  <input type="button" value="Submit">

</form> 

<p>If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page called "/action_page.php".</p>
<p>Go to the <a href="{% url 'index' %}"> guestbook </a> itself</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Essentially, I would like to know how to simply create an HTML object (that is functional) and apply the CSS to it.

Answer (score 0):

So If I am understanding the question correctly, you are having no issue applying CSS to HTML you hard code, and it is the HTML that is generated with Django's templating system that you are having trouble getting your CSS to stick to yes? I would inspect the rendered HTML of that django generated "comment" field. I think you will find that your CSS rules are not applying because the HTML is not what you expect. In other words, your selector: `textarea[type=textarea]` is not matching the comment field because it is probably not a textarea, or does not have a type=textarea attribute.

You can add attributes in the widget definition itself if you are having trouble getting a CSS rule to stick, but I use [This](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) library a lot. It let's you add attributes in the template.